# Resize image after retrieve it from data base

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

hey there i want to resize image after retriving from database here is my code

```
        try{
        String sql ="SELECT Image from piece where Code_Piece = 
        "+jTextField1.getText()+"";
        stmt=maconnexion.Obtenirconnexion().createStatement();
        ResultSet Rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        if(Rs.next()){
            byte[]imagedata= Rs.getBytes("Image");
            format = new ImageIcon(imagedata);

            lbl_image.setIcon(ResizeImage(format, null));
        }
         }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("No Fille");
       }
```

i got this error "java.lang.NullPointerException" and i use this method to resize my image

```
        String imgPath = null;    
       public ImageIcon ResizeImage(String imagePath, byte[] pic){

       ImageIcon myImage = null;
       if(imagePath != null){

      myImage = new ImageIcon(imagePath);

     }else{
      myImage = new ImageIcon(pic);
      }
       Image img = myImage.getImage();
        Image img2 = img.getScaledInstance(lbl_image.getWidth(), 
     lbl_image.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
       ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(img2);
         return image;
          }
```

Comment: Where are you getting the NullPointerException? Is the problem with retrieving that data from the database or with processing it?

Comment: With the processing of resizing the image

Comment: @BrianMikeyHalbert i still have that error, do u have any ideas ??